# ¿como hago para determinar si un grafo es dirigido o no?

Tags: matrices, teoría-de-grafos

les cuento, estoy haciendo una aplicación en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) donde represento un grafo a través de la matriz de adyacencia, dicha matriz la ingresa el usuario, la pregunta es como puedo hacer un método que me diga si dicha matriz es de un grafo dirigido o no. la idea es que simplemente el usuario tenga que oprimir un botón y salga un mensaje diciendo "la matriz ingresada es dirigida" o en su defecto, no lo es.

Answer (score 0):

Supón que tienes un grafo con los sigientes nodos:

```
Nodo1 <==> Nodo2
Nodo1 ==> Nodo3
Nodo3 ==> Nodo2
```

Entonces tu matriz de adyacencia de un modo más visual sería algo como:

```
        Nodo1 Nodo2 Nodo3
Nodo1           .     .
Nodo2    .
Nodo3           .
```

La forma fácil es fijarte en las simetrías.
Como hay un camino entre `Nodo1` y `Nodo2` y visceversa, en la matriz hallarás la simetría en base a la diagonal:

```
        Nodo1 Nodo2
Nodo1           .     
Nodo2    .
```

Hasta ese momentos tenemos un grafo no dirigido ya que **en un grafo no dirigido es aquel en el que todas sus aristas son bidireccionales**.

Esto quiere decir que si numeramos nuestra matriz bidireccional

```
   i       0   1
j        Nodo1 Nodo2
0 Nodo1           .     
1 Nodo2    .
```

Notamos que para cada `Matriz[i][j] == Matriz[j][i]`.

Ahora agregando los demás nodos

```
     i     0     1     2
j        Nodo1 Nodo2 Nodo3
0 Nodo1           .     .
1 Nodo2    .
2 Nodo3           .
```

La regla no se cumple, por lo tanto si tenemos un **grafo dirigido**, a pesar de que si extraemos el subgrafo con el **Nodo1** y **Nodo2** este **subgrafo** sería un **grafo no-dirigido**.

Ahora en código en vez de usar un `.` generalmente se usan valores binarios o pesos entre los aristas.

¿Qué pasa si tienen peso?

Bueno, hasta el momento el espacio significaba peso infinito, y el `.` significaba sin peso, las mismas reglas siguen aplicando.

Comment: ahh vale, ya tengo mas idea, lo que tendría que hacer es recorrer las filas y columnas de mi matris y verificar que se cumpla esto, Matriz[i][j] == Matriz[j][i] ?osea ese seria mi condicional, verdad?

Comment: sí, esa es una manera :)